# Windows webserivce starts and stops automatically

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, windows-7-x64

This message is displayed when running my windows service.

```
The [service name] service on local computer started and then stopped. 
Some Services stop automatically if they are not in use by another services or programs.
```

I am not sure what is causing this error. Below is the code for my service. My code uses another class called MagentoSalesOrder. I ran this code as a console application first and it worked just fine. I believe this what is causing the error. When I comment out the lines that use that class my service runs fine for printing test to a file.

Imports MyFirstService.MagentoSalesOrder
Public Class MyFirstService
    Dim WithEvents timer1 As New System.Timers.Timer

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    timer1.Interval = 10000
    timer1.Start()
    WriteLog(Me.ServiceName & " has started ...")

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    WriteLog(Me.ServiceName & " has stopped ...")
End Sub

Private Sub timer1_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles timer1.Elapsed
    WriteLog(Me.ServiceName & " is running ...")
End Sub

Private Sub WriteLog(ByVal strMessage As String)
    Dim strPath As String, file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim test As New MagentoSalesOrder()
    strPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\MyService.log"
    file = New System.IO.StreamWriter(strPath, True)
    Dim arr = test.BuildPreOrder()
    If (arr.Length > 0) Then

        For Each element As Long In arr
            file.WriteLine("PreOrder created: " + element)
        Next
    Else
        file.WriteLine("No orders to process")
    End If
    'file.WriteLine("Test")
    file.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

So I found out my error was coming from the file.writeline in my foreach loop.

Changing **element** to **element.toString** in my writefile fixed my service.

Comment: Are you using Try/Catch blocks around whatever the `MagentoSalesOrder` class is doing?  It's probably throwing an exception and stopping your service.

Comment: Yes I am. I also found my error, but maybe you can explain why it is occurs. I will update my question.

Comment: Probably because you're trying to concatenate a `Long` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from trying to concatenate a Long to a String.

Changing element to element.toString in my writefile fixed my service.